# How to passed the values get in array in jquery to a controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i am newbie in codeigniter and jquery but the website i am maintaining now uses this framework and language,.,.the problem is that i have these text fields and hidden fields in a page,,.i want to get the values of these input fields through jquery,.,passed these through $.post of jquery to a Controller,.,.i know how to track the flow but i do not know how to get the passed value in my controller and i am totally newbie in codeigniter and jquery,,i want to learn and at the same time finished the task,.,.
heres my code in my view page..

```
 <?php $date = date('m/d/Y');
    $ts = strtotime($date);
    $year = date('o', $ts);
    $week = date('W', $ts);
    for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
           $ts = strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$i);
        ?><input type="text" name="days" class="days" /><input type="hidden" id="date_now" name="date_now" value="<?php print date("Y-m-d", $ts); ?>" />

    } 
?>
```

and my jquery for text input

```
$(".saveTimeSheet").click(function() { 
    var days_array     = [];
    var date_now_array = [];

    $('.days').each(function() {
            days_array.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.post("<?php print base_url().'index.php/MyController/saveTimeTable'?>", {days_array: days_array},
        function(data){
            if(data=='success')
            {
                alert('success');
            }
            else{
                error_message(data);
            }
    });
 });
```

MyController Code...

```
function saveTimeTable()
{
   $idnum=$this->session->userdata('id');       
       $duration=$this->input->post('days_array')*3600;
       $this->mmyhr->modeSaveTimeTable($idnum, $duration);
}
```

my Model code(mmyhr)

```
function modeSaveTimeTable($idnum, $duration)
{
   $this->db->set('employee_id', $idnum);
   $this->db->set('duration', $duration);
   $this->db->insert('hs_hr_time_event');
 }
```

could anyone help me,.,.please....

Comment: Please take the time to use proper grammar, spelling, and format your code.

Comment: I agree please properly format. The fact that you broke out of PHP tags here ?><td><?php just for a TD tag makes it harder to read not to mention harder to maintain.

Comment: So what exactly is or isn't happening?

Comment: So the problem is with the database part of the code? You can receive the array of data from the jQuery post data and the data the model receives (`$idnum` & `$duration`) are getting the correct values?) ??

Comment: I still don't get it because your `days_array` will be received as array. How can you multiply it directly without using loop? `$this->input->post('days_array')*3600`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code above your controller should be like this:

```
function saveTimeTable()
{
    $idnum=$this->session->userdata('id');
    $days_array = $this->input->post('days_array');

    foreach($days_array as $day){
        $duration=$day*3600;
        $this->mmyhr->modeSaveTimeTable($idnum, $duration);
    }    
}
```